# Using IQueryable<Model> data in Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iqueryable

I am very new to Javascript and pretty much just plugging and playing with this example, but here it is at a high level.

In my controller I am returning an Iqueryable to my view, which I then want to build a grid from.

My javascript looks like this:

```
$.ig.loader({
    ready: function () {
        $("#grid1").igGrid({
            dataSource: Model,
            primaryKey: "BatchNumber",
            autoGenerateColumns: false,
            height: "350px",
            width: "800px",
            columns: [
                { headerText: "Batch Number", key: "BatchNumber", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Batch Group Item Date", key: "BatchGroupItemDate", dataType: "string" },
                { headerText: "Batch Comment", key: "BatchComment", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Number Of Documents", key: "NumberOfDocuments", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Total Transfered", key: "TotalTransfered", dataType: "date" },
                { headerText: "Not Transfered", key: "NotTransfered", dataType: "date" },
                { headerText: "CoId", key: "CoId", dataType: "date" }
            ],

    });
    }
});
```

Where the model is an IQueryable.  I am using infragistics grid libraries as well.  When I render the page nothing seems to happen and I get no output when monitoring the javascript in firefox.  I am not sure where to start debugging this issue as my javascript knowledge is pretty limited.  I am running asp.net mvc 4 as well.

Comment: Take a look at the source code that is being sent from the server. What does the line that contain `dataSource: ` look like?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape and JSON encode your model:

```
dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error when trying to implement it this way. I did a simple print to screen with the following `@{
    var bleh = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    
}
<p>@bleh</p>` and it seemed to print the correctly encoded JSON

Comment: If you're talking about a JavaScript syntax error in your view, just ignore it, Razor is stupid sometimes, and this makes it freak out for some reason, at least in version 2, I haven't noticed any problems yet in Razor 3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in model you have a set of objects and want to render these objects inside of your view as a javascript. Add this code right to your view:

```
<script text="text/javascript">
var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)); // converts an object to javascript object

$.ig.loader({
    ready: function () {
        $("#grid1").igGrid({
            dataSource: data, // your data
            primaryKey: "BatchNumber",
            autoGenerateColumns: false,
            height: "350px",
            width: "800px",
            columns: [
                { headerText: "Batch Number", key: "BatchNumber", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Batch Group Item Date", key: "BatchGroupItemDate", dataType: "string" },
                { headerText: "Batch Comment", key: "BatchComment", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Number Of Documents", key: "NumberOfDocuments", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Total Transfered", key: "TotalTransfered", dataType: "date" },
                { headerText: "Not Transfered", key: "NotTransfered", dataType: "date" },
                { headerText: "CoId", key: "CoId", dataType: "date" }
            ],

    });
    }
});
</script>
```

Make sure to add a reference to NewtonSoft.Json with PM console:

```
PM> install-package NewtonSoft.Json
```

If you have your javascript in a separate file, you may want to wrap your js code into function. Like this:

(Scripts.js file)

```
function load_data(data)
{

$.ig.loader({
    ready: function () {
        $("#grid1").igGrid({
            dataSource: data, // your data
            primaryKey: "BatchNumber",
            autoGenerateColumns: false,
            height: "350px",
            width: "800px",
            columns: [
                { headerText: "Batch Number", key: "BatchNumber", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Batch Group Item Date", key: "BatchGroupItemDate", dataType: "string" },
                { headerText: "Batch Comment", key: "BatchComment", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Number Of Documents", key: "NumberOfDocuments", dataType: "number" },
                { headerText: "Total Transfered", key: "TotalTransfered", dataType: "date" },
                { headerText: "Not Transfered", key: "NotTransfered", dataType: "date" },
                { headerText: "CoId", key: "CoId", dataType: "date" }
            ],

    });
    }
});

}
```

Your cshtml file:

```
...other html code...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)); // converts an object to javascript object
    load_data(data);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```